# Merging subscriberkeys and records

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, merge, merge-field, subscriber

We are facing a issue, where we want to be able to merge records for 2 or more subscriber keys. We know that this is not a standard functionality, so how should we best approach this?

The key element is to have the campaign history on the the final merged subscriber key. So any campaigns that subscriber 2 and 3 has been in should be visible on subscriber 1.

I have been trying to look for solution to handle this, but I can't seem to find any good ways to approach it. Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to 'merge' subscribers. Every individual Contact with a unqiue Subscriber Key also had system defined attributes which can only be changed by Salesforce Service Team and requires their side action, which is quite costly.

They would be able to change Subscriber Key from one value to another and retain the history, but not merge two (or more) Contacts into one entity.

What they may be able to do (also for a cost) is change the Tracking information Contact, to point to a Subscriber you choose.  I've heard something of sorts being done in the past. This means the other Contacts will continue to exist but as 'clean' Contacts who you can safely delete via Contact Builder.

You'll need to escalate this with your Account Executive and engage in talks with their side SMFC Solution Architects.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had a feeling that it was something like this we were facing. I guess we will have to look into, if we can solve our issue another way than by merging the records.